# Add custom wordpress templete to grandchild pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently working on a Wordpress theme and need to set custom templates to child and grandchild pages automatically, so a client wouldn't need to worry about selecting which template to choose.

The code I have already is:

```
<?php
 if( $post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
   get_template_part('child');
  } else {
      get_template_part('parent');
  }
  ?>
```

The code is placed within page.php. This works great for child pages but I need to include something like 'if grandchild apply grandchild.php'.

Any help or advice will be much appreciated. Thanks =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
if( count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) >= 2 ) {
   enter code here
}
```

Making use of http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I got it to work with combing bit of your example with the code I had before for example: 
`<?php
        if( count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 1 ) {
            get_template_part('child');
         } elseif ( count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) > 0 ) {
             get_template_part('grandchild');
          } else {
             get_template_part('parent');
        }
        ?>`